# where did my environment variable go?

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to use an environment variable in a bash script that needs to run as `sudo` with `source`.

I have the following file (my_file.sh)

```
 echo "this is DOMAIN = $DOMAIN"
```

I have the `DOMAIN` environment variable in my session..

and now I need to run

```
  sudo -E bash -c "source ./my_file.sh"
```

but the output does not display the value for `$DOMAIN`. instead it is empty.

if I change the command to be

```
  sudo -E bash -c "echo $DOMAIN"
```

I see the correct value..

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I totally missed that you were already using `-E`.  In that case, are you sure you `export`ed the variable?

Comment: In the second example, `$DOMAIN` is expanded by the current shell *before* it runs `sudo`.

Comment: OMG.. it did not export!! I swear that export was there before..

Comment: @chepner so I used your explanation and instead of exporting the original variable (which might affect something else.. ) I did `sudo -E bash -c "export DOMAIN=$DOMAIN; source ..."`.. and it works! thanks :) the explanation is awesome.

Comment: The `export` isn't making a difference there; it's the double quotes that allow `$DOMAIN` to be expanded. `sudo -E bash -c "DOMAIN=$DOMAIN; source ..."` would work just as well. Try `sudo -E bash -c 'echo $DOMAIN'` with and without exporting `DOMAIN` first to see the difference single quotes make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the command line:

```
sudo -E bash -c "source ./my_file.sh"
```

you are running a script that may refer to environment variables that would need to be `export`ed from a parent shell to be visible.

On the other hand:

```
sudo -E bash -c "echo $DOMAIN"
```

expands the value of `$DOMAIN` *in the parent shell*, not inside your `sudo` line.

To demonstrate this, try your "working" solution with single quotes:

```
sudo -E bash -c 'echo $DOMAIN'
```

And to make things go, try exporting the variable:

```
export DOMAIN
sudo -E bash -c "source ./my_file.sh"
```

Or alternately, pass $DOMAIN on the command line:

```
sudo -E bash -c "source ./my_file.sh $DOMAIN"
```

And have your script refer to `$1`.

Comment: so according to your answer I should see $DOMAIN no? I export it and then run `sudo -E bash -c "source ./my_file.sh"` and you said "script that may refer to environment variables that would need to be exported from a parent shell to be visible.. so I should see it.. or am I missing something?

Comment: @guymograbi, with the single-quoted `echo` and the variable not exported, you should see a blank line, because as far as the sudo'd bash is concerned, `$DOMAIN` is unset and expands to nothing. With the variable exported, it will be visible to the sudo'd `bash` and your script. And yes, it *may* refer to environment variables. You didn't include the contents of your script, so I have no way to know what's in it. :-)